# Error get value when type a text in javascript

Tags: jquery

I have a sample code:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="ac_input"/>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="GO"/>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.submit').click(function(){
         var q = $('.ac_input').val();
         alert(q);
    });  
});
```

When I type "test" on input text, result is alert("undefined");

How to fix error when type "test" is result is `<input type="text" value="test" class="ac_input"/>`

Comment: When you type "test", `q` is "test". http://jsfiddle.net/8bBtP/

Comment: Are there any other elements on the page with the `ac_input` class?

Comment: Works fine for me in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8HTU/) - what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Change the class="ac_input" to id="ac_input". You should use classes when it's something more generic. In this case you want to target that specific input using javascript so ID is a better option.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="ac_input"/>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="GO"/>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.submit').click(function(){
         var q = $('#ac_input').val();
         alert(q);
    });  
});
```